# Trying To convert String to lower/upper case respectively

Tags: java, string

I'm trying to convert string to lowercase if it is uppercase and vice-versa. The code doesn't work as expected. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

```java
public class LowerNadUpperCase {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String output = "Elmar DidOkLTWdeee";
        System.out.println(toAlternativeString(output));
    }

    public static String toAlternativeString(String string) {
        String output = "";
        for(int i = 0; i < string.length(); i++) {
            char c = string.charAt(i);
            if(Character.isLetter(c)){
                if(Character.isLowerCase(c)){
                    output += Character.toUpperCase(c);
                    if(Character.isUpperCase(c)){
                        output += Character.toLowerCase(c);
                    }  else{
                        output += c;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return output;
    }
}
```

Comment: You've nested your upper case check inside your lower case check.  Which means you're only ever checking for upper case letters if you already know they're lower case.  You need to insert a `}` character to close off the lower case check before you do your upper case check.

Comment: I have checked that one too but the code still fails.

Answer (score 0):

Convert using predefine method try this

```
static void convertOpposite(StringBuffer str)
    {
        int ln = str.length();
 
        // Conversion using predefined methods
        for (int i = 0; i < ln; i++) {
            Character c = str.charAt(i);
            if (Character.isLowerCase(c))
                str.replace(i, i + 1,
                            Character.toUpperCase(c) + "");
            else
                str.replace(i, i + 1,
                            Character.toLowerCase(c) + "");
        }
    }

public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        StringBuffer str = new StringBuffer("asasDAaQWADa");
        convertOpposite(str);
 
        System.out.println(str);
    }
```

Dont take extra variable it will convert by replace character.

Comment: Can we discuess the issues with [`StringBuffer`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/StringBuffer.html) and the fact that even the JavaDocs recommend `StringBuilder` in a single threaded environment - just saying

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.*;
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        String a=sc.nextLine();
        String res="";
        for(int i=0;i<a.length();i++){
            if(Character.isLowerCase(a.charAt(i))){
                res=res+Character.toUpperCase(a.charAt(i)));
            }
            else{
                res=res+Character.toLowerCase(a.charAt(i)));
            }
        }
        System.out.println(res);
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the reason for the casts?

Answer (score 0):

So, your basic problem is in your logic (I know, obvious right)

```
if (Character.isLetter(c)) {
    if (Character.isLowerCase(c)) {
        output += Character.toUpperCase(c);
        if (Character.isUpperCase(c)) {
            output += Character.toLowerCase(c);
        } else {
            output += c;
        }
    }
}
```

- if `c` is not a letter ... do nothing
- else if `c` is lower case, append upper cased `c`. Now this is where is gets interesting, if `c` is upper case, which it can't be since we know it's lower case, append (the original) `c` to output ... again

This is where doing "desk checking" (ie, layout your variables and walking through your code by hand and writing down what's going) is so very powerful.

What you probably mean to do, is something more like...

```
if (Character.isLetter(c)) {
    if (Character.isLowerCase(c)) {
        output += Character.toUpperCase(c);
    } else if (Character.isUpperCase(c)) {
        output += Character.toLowerCase(c);
    }
} else {
    output += c;
}
```

Although you probably don't "really" need the `isLetter` check (I mean, what is upper/lower case `1` anyway ‍♂️).

This would make your method look more like...

```
public static String toAlternativeString(String string) {
    String output = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < string.length(); i++) {
        char c = string.charAt(i);
        if (Character.isLetter(c)) {
            if (Character.isLowerCase(c)) {
                output += Character.toUpperCase(c);
            } else if (Character.isUpperCase(c)) {
                output += Character.toLowerCase(c);
            }
        } else {
            output += c;
        }
    }
    return output;
}
```

Now, before any one jumps down my throat over the poor performance of `String` concatenation, I know, but I don't really think that's the point of the question

But just in case...

```
public static String toAlternativeString(String string) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(string.length());
    for (char c : string.toCharArray()) {
        if (Character.isUpperCase(c)) {
            sb.append(Character.toLowerCase(c));
        } else {
            sb.append(Character.toUpperCase(c));
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

`StringBuilder` is "generally" a better solution if you want to do `String` concatenation in Java, but this might be some what of a over kill for this example.

So, taking an input like `Elmar DidOkLTWdeee 123456` the above methods will output `eLMAR dIDoKltwDEEE 123456`

Comment: Thank you so much for the clarification. Your code is much clear and lesser than mine.

Answer (score 0):

Elaborating @Dawood ibn Kareem's comment, you don't need the nested loop a simple `if-else` would do it.

```
if(Character.isLetter(c)){
    if(Character.isLowerCase(c)){
        output += Character.toUpperCase(c);
    }
    else {
        output += Character.toLowerCase(c);
    }
}
```

Comment: I will encourage StringBuilder and whole ordeal should should be as simple as `c = Character.isLowerCase(c)?Character.toUpperCase(c):c;`. There is no good reason to check isLetter

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to do it using the [stream API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/architect-streams-pt2.html).

```java
import java.util.Objects;

public class LowerAndUpperCase {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String output = "Elmar DidOkLTWdeee";
        System.out.println(toAlternativeString(output));
    }

    public static String toAlternativeString(String string) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(string);
        StringBuilder sb = string.chars()
                                 .map(c -> Character.isLowerCase((char) c) ? Character.toUpperCase((char) c) : Character.isUpperCase((char) c) ? Character.toLowerCase((char) c) : (char) c)
                                 .collect(() -> new StringBuilder(),
                                          (s, c) -> s.append((char) c),
                                          (s1, s2) -> s1.append(s2));
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

- Method [isLowerCase](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Character.html#isLowerCase(char)) also checks whether its method argument is a letter so no need to call method `isLetter` first.
- Method [chars](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#chars()) returns an `IntStream`, hence the casts to `char`.
- The mapper returns the upper-case of the supplied character – if it is lower-case – or the lower-case of the supplied character – if it is upper-case – or the character itself if it is neither upper nor lower case.
- In the arguments to the `collect` method, the type of `s` and `s1` and `s2` is `StringBuilder`.

Here is the output when I run the above code.

```
eLMAR dIDoKltwDEEE
```

Note that the space in the original string is maintained (since the space character is neither upper-case nor lower-case).